# как правильно остановить все потоки кроме главного?

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Хочу сделать такую задачу. Создать 36 потоков. Остановить каждый (wait() ). и затем по команде notifyAll(), одновремено разбудить все и тот кто первый замониторит метод должен будет написать "Первым взял поток №n", где n - имя потока.
вот что получилось:

```
import java.util.Objects;

class Roulette implements Runnable{
    public Integer count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Object args = null;

        synchronized.wait();



        synchronized (count) {
            if (count < 1){
                System.out.printf("Первым взял %s \n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
                count++;
            }

        }

    }



}


public class Casino {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        for (int i=1; i<37; i++){
            Thread potok = new Thread(new Roulette());
            potok.setName("Поток: " + i);
            potok.start();
            synchronized (potok) {
                potok.wait();   
            }

        }
        synchronized (args) {
            Roulette.class.notifyAll(); 
        }



    }

}
```

ругается на synchronized.wait();, объясните каким образом и куда его нужно поставить, что бы вначале потоки были созданы и остановлены, пока главный поток не скажет notifyAll();

Попробовал что-то таким образом:

```
import java.util.Objects;

class Roulette implements Runnable{
    public Integer count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Object args = null;

        synchronized(count){
            try {
                count.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        synchronized (count) {
            if (count < 1){
                System.out.printf("Первым взял %s \n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
                count++;
            }

        }

    }



}


public class Casino {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        for (int i=1; i<37; i++){
            Thread potok = new Thread(new Roulette());
            potok.setName("Поток: " + i);
            potok.start();
            /*synchronized (potok) {
                potok.wait();   
            }*/

        }

        someMethod();
        /*synchronized (args) {
            Roulette.class.notifyAll(); 
        }*/



    }
    public static void someMethod(){
        synchronized(Roulette.class){
            Roulette.class.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

теперь ошибок при компиляции не выдает, и когда дебажишь вроде и notifyAll() запускается. Но программа не останавливается. Результат не печатается.

попробовал наследоваться от треда никаких изменений.

```
import java.util.Objects;

class Roulette extends Thread{
    public volatile Integer count = 0;
    public Integer count2 = 1;
    Object args = new Object();
    public synchronized void weiting(){

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void counting(Integer count){
        if (count < 1){
            System.out.printf("Первым взял %s \n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
            count++;
        }

    }

    public synchronized  void someMethod(){
           // synchronized(Roulette.class){
                notifyAll();
            //}
        }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        weiting();
        counting(count);    




    }



}


public class Casino {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        for (int i=1; i<37; i++){
            Thread potok = new Thread(new Roulette());
            potok.setName("Поток: " + i);
            potok.start();
            /*synchronized (potok) {
                potok.wait();   
            }*/

        }


        new Roulette().someMethod();
        /*synchronized (args) {
            Roulette.class.notifyAll(); 
        }*/



    }
    //public synchronized static void someMethod(){
       // synchronized(Roulette.class){
      //    Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
        //}
    //}

}
```

программа работает, но не останавливается. почему не могу понять, вроде же главным потоком вызываю notyfyAll все равно зависает и ничего не печатает.

Comment: «ругается на `synchronized.wait();`» — а выяснить, как именно «ругается», оставляется нам в качестве упражнения? И да, `synchronized` — это, кажется, ключевое слово. То есть ваша проблема не в неправильной работе многопоточности, а просто не компилируется, правильно?

Comment: @  VladD, да. начитался по синхронизации, но так ничего не могу понять, почему не компилится. почему не отстанавливает.

Comment: wait - это метод, а synchronized - это не объект, на котором можно что-либо вызвать, это ключевое слово

Comment: @etki я исправил и добавил изменения в основной вопрос,но  все равно ничего не получается

Comment: Ну вы же сами пишете synchronized-методы, пока один тред находится внутри synchronized-метода, другой тред не может зайти в любой synchronized-метод. Вот у вс все и висит на weiting

Comment: @etki, но если у потока выполняется weit() разве он не отдает монитор как пишут. а если монитор отдан, то почему тогда следующий поток не должен зайти в synchronized-методы???

Comment: Да, тупанул. Сейчас вы в обоих примерах вызываете wait / notify на абсолютно разных объектах.